# Composition of rotation and reflection

Tags: geometry, linear-transformations

Suppose you find a spatial isometry and you want to classify it. You find out the only real eigenvalue is -1. Also, there is a unique fixed point c.

In this type of cases i was told that we have a composition of a rotation and a relfection. However...

How can i derive the angle of the rotation or the axis of reflection?

Is the eigenspace of - 1 related to something here?

Thanks

Comment: A plane isometry? Or a spatial isometry?

Comment: Spatial isometry!